# Set p:selectBooleanCheckbox value to bean with ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, datatable

Hi i have a primefaces datatable with dynamic columns

```
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable id="cars" var="car" value="#{formBean.carsSmall}" 
        filteredValue="#{formBean.filteredCars}">
        <p:columns value="#{formBean.columns}" var="column" 
            columnIndexVar="colIndex"sortBy="#{column.property}" 
                filterBy="#{column.property}">
            <f:facet name="header">
                #{column.header}
            </f:facet>
            <p:outputPanel 
                rendered="#{(column.header eq 'CHECKVALUE1') or (column.header eq 'CHECKVALUE2')}" >
                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{car.checkValue}"  id="checkboxId">
                </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
            </p:outputPanel>
            <p:outputPanel 
                rendered="#{(column.header ne 'CHECKVALUE1') and (column.header ne 'CHECKVALUE2')}" >
                #{car[column.property]}
            </p:outputPanel>
        </p:columns>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

and i want to submit checkbox values to bean with ajax how could i do that ??
I tried to write something like:

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{car.checkValue}"  id="checkboxId">
    <p:ajax update="@form"/>
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

But the value doesnt set to bean..

Comment: Have you tried specifying the event you need? `event="click"`

Comment: @Xtreme: it defaults to click already in case of checkbox/radiobutton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{car.checkValue}"  id="checkboxId">
        <p:ajax update=":form" listener="#{car.addMessage}"/>  
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

Java Bean Class -

```
public void addMessage()
{
    //Your Java Code goes here.
}
```